# Flutter multipart request along name value pair to server

Tags: dart, flutter, multipart

I have to send to multipart request to server along with name value pair to server i mean id along with it. Can you please help me how to send id along with multipart files.

```dart
Upload() async {
  var stream = new https.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(Files[0].openRead()));
  var length = await Files[0].length();


  var stream1 = new https.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(Files[1].openRead()));
  var length1 = await Files[1].length();

  var stream2 = new https.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(Files[2].openRead()));
  var length2 = await Files[2].length();



  var uri = Uri.parse(openurl);

  var request = new https.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
  var multipartFile1 = new https.MultipartFile('XX', stream, length,
      filename: basename(Files[0].path));
  var multipartFile2 = new https.MultipartFile('YY', stream1, length1,
      filename: basename(Files[0].path));

  var multipartFile3 = new https.MultipartFile('ZZ', stream2, length2,
      filename: basename(Files[0].path));



  //contentType: new MediaType('image', 'png'));

  request.files.add(multipartFile1);
  request.files.add(multipartFile2);
  request.files.add(multipartFile3);
  request.fields.addAll(other)

  var response = await request.send();
  print(response.statusCode);
  response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
    print(value);
  });
}
```

Thanks in advance

Sathish

Comment: For HTTP requests I'd recommend using [Dio library](https://pub.dev/packages/dio). It will help you avoid limitations of standard networking libs.

Answer (score 4):

I just had a problem similar to this. I had to upload an image along a key-value pair. I realize that I could upload the key-value pair using request.fields:

```
var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

request.fields['description'] = 'description';
request.fields['File-Name'] = 'FILENAME.jpg';
request.fields['qr_size'] = '3';
```